# Adapting State Switch with button push from Arduino Code to Python for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I have started to learn programming Raspberry Pi instead of Arduino. There is some code that I wrote to work in Arduino, but I am wondering how I adapt it to the Python language. Thanks for any help!

```
int mode = 0, buttonState, startMillis, timeDiff;
const int BlueLED = 3, RedLED = 6, buttonPin = 12;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BlueLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RedLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  buttonPressed();

  switch(mode % 3){
    case 0:
      state0();
      break;

    case 1:
      state1();
      break;

    case 2:
      state2();
      break;
  }

  //Serial.println(timeDiff);
}

void state0(){
  analogWrite(BlueLED, 0);
  analogWrite(RedLED, 0);
  Serial.println("Off");
}

void state1(){
  analogWrite(BlueLED, 255);
  analogWrite(RedLED, 0);
  Serial.println("Blue");
}

void state2(){
  analogWrite(BlueLED, 0);
  analogWrite(RedLED, 255);
  Serial.println("Red");
}

void buttonPressed(){
  // debounce
  int check1 = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  delay(10);
  int check2 = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if(check1 == check2){
    if(check1 != buttonState){
      mode++;
      startMillis = millis();
    }
  }
```

I've tried the match and case commands, and if else statements, but I cant get it to work quite correctly

Comment: That's a very broad question. What particular issues are you having trying to translate this code? There are many examples online of how to interact with the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi.

Comment: I am able to read pin inputs and out put signals to GPIO Pins, I ama mainly looking for help for adapting the code for the case switching with a button push, mainly this block of code:                                                                                        
 `buttonPressed();

  switch(mode % 3){
    case 0:
      state0();
      break;

    case 1:
      state1();
      break;

    case 2:
      state2();
      break;`

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything arduino specific in that code. As posted it doesn't appear to require any adaptation.